# How to use the inverse function theorem to find a local inverse?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a function $F(x,y)=(x^2 - y^2, xy)$ and I need to show that it has an inverse. How do I find the inverse of this function using the inverse function theorem? I did this a while ago and now I can't find it in my notes. I recall having to make $u = x^2 - y^2$ and $v = xy$ but then I'm lost.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Are you sure the variables are complex here? That's not usually implied by the letters $x$ and $y$. IF they are complex, then the [real-analysis] tag is misplaced.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, there shouldnt be the complex tag.

Comment: What's the domain of $F$? For instance it will not be injective on any neighborhood of the origin since $F(x,0)=F(-x,0)$ for any $x$.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention  (x, y) ∈ R^2

Comment: Do you need to show a concrete formula for computing a local inverse or merely prove that it exists? The latter is simply a matter of computing the Jacobian and appealing to the inverse function theorem; the former needs some ad-hoc calculation.

Comment: This is the full question,  In which points (a, b) ∈ R^2  does f have a local inverse, i.e., for which points (a, b) does there exist a neighbourhood U of (a, b) such that f is injective on U? So I assume the latter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For a concrete formula write, as you say, $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=xy$. Then $y=v/x$, so that 
$$u=x^2-\frac{v^2}{x^2}$$
which implies that 
$$x^4-ux^2-v^2=0.$$
Solve the above equation for $x$ using the quadratic formula and substitute back into $y=v/x$ to find the equation for $y.$

Of course care must be taken when choosing signs for particular regions of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is all I needed to know.

Comment: You are welcome, John.

Answer (score 2):

The IFT proves the local existence of inverse function, but is not useful for finding the explicit form of the inverse function.
In this case,
$$
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} =
\left|\matrix{2x&y\cr-2y&x}\right|=2(x^2+y^2)\ne 0\iff(x,y)\ne(0,0)
$$
and the inverse exists locally in any point except the origin.